# Passing a parameter into an Ajax url in Scala Play

Tags: jquery, ajax, scala, playframework

I have an Ajax route that takes in an optional string; I'm getting this string from a HTML select tag but when I pass the parameter into the url route it doesn't register as a variable.

```
$("#submit-button").on('click', function () {

var getOption = $( "#option" ).find(":selected").text(); 
var idToGet = $("#hi").val();
   $.ajax({
       url: '@routes.ApplicationController.getStuff(Some(getOption))', //requires an option[string]
       type: 'GET',
       data: {get_param: idToGet},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
       $.each(data, function (index, element) {
         alert("hi")
       });
     }
   });
 });
```

`getOption` can't be passed into the url route. I've tried implementing it as a function and calling it but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `GET`, the only way is to use absoluteURL and queryparam.

assuming your param name is `option`:

```
$("#submit-button").on('click', function () {

var getOption = $( "#option" ).find(":selected").text(); 
var idToGet = $("#hi").val();
   $.ajax({
       url: '@{routes.ApplicationController.getStuff(None).absoluteURL()}?option='+getOption, //requires an option[string]
       type: 'GET',
       data: {get_param: idToGet},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
       $.each(data, function (index, element) {
         alert("hi")
       });
     }
   });
 });
```

The drawback is, if you change the name of your parameter in Scala controller, you have to change it in the view.

Comment: Thanks! What would the syntax be for the URL if I had multiple options?

Comment: `?option=opt1&option=opt2`

Comment: It has to be done with Javascript. You can make something like that : `var selectedOptions = $('#option').val();var queryparam = "";selectedOptions.forEach(function(entry) {
    queryparam += "option="+entry+"&";
});`

Comment: Pretty sure you can find something better ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give Javascript a go.